# FirebaseApp.configure() crashes in IOS12

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ios12

I got my app works well in every ios version, however; when updated to ios 12, all users who are in ios 12 get crashed from launching. I am trying to debug and found that FirebaseApp.configure() is causing crash. Although, it works fine with stimulator even run ios 12 and also works fine when i open the open through xcode. I tried to kill the app and opened it again -> got crashed immediately. Here is the crash logs:

```
Incident Identifier: 2047E97F-A583-4F35-B766-A4577CEC6F53
CrashReporter Key:   220c3e605534bc1c5752d04b41745c2b237ddeb6
Hardware Model:      iPhone11,6
Process:             CRACC [672]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3F210234-7C84-46E2-800C-5D7176DD5548/CRACC.app/CRACC
Identifier:          Team-LLC.CRACC
Version:             1 (1.5)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           Team-LLC.CRACC [616]


Date/Time:           2018-10-01 20:05:05.9760 -0400
Launch Time:         2018-10-01 20:05:05.5080 -0400
OS Version:          iPhone OS 12.0 (16A366)
Baseband Version:    1.00.07
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  9

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001fed439dc __ulock_wait + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001febbcc2c _dispatch_wait_on_address + 136
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001febbd6e8 _dispatch_group_wait_slow + 44
3   CRACC                           0x00000001050e23e4 0x104a18000 + 7119844
4   CRACC                           0x00000001050df64c 0x104a18000 + 7108172
5   CRACC                           0x00000001050de978 0x104a18000 + 7104888
6   CRACC                           0x00000001050de584 0x104a18000 + 7103876
7   CRACC                           0x00000001050d2cc8 0x104a18000 + 7056584
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001febbc30c _dispatch_client_callout + 20
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001febbe174 _dispatch_once_callout + 32
10  CRACC                           0x00000001050d2a3c 0x104a18000 + 7055932
11  CRACC                           0x00000001050d2e7c 0x104a18000 + 7057020
12  CRACC                           0x00000001051088a0 0x104a18000 + 7276704
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001febbc30c _dispatch_client_callout + 20
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001febbe174 _dispatch_once_callout + 32
15  CRACC                           0x00000001051086a8 0x104a18000 + 7276200
16  CRACC                           0x000000010510a124 0x104a18000 + 7282980
17  Foundation                      0x00000001ffb69c10 -[__NSObserver _doit:] + 336
18  Foundation                      0x00000001ffc51908 __67-[NSNotificationCenter addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock:]_block_invoke + 40
19  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001ff122528 __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 28
20  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001ff1224e8 ___CFXRegistrationPost_block_invoke + 68
21  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001ff121990 _CFXRegistrationPost + 420
22  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001ff12161c ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 100
23  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001ff0971b4 -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1412
24  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001ff1210a0 _CFXNotificationPost + 712
25  Foundation                      0x00000001ffb3ed34 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 72
26  CRACC                           0x000000010529c0f4 0x104a18000 + 8929524
27  CRACC                           0x0000000105297028 0x104a18000 + 8908840
28  CRACC                           0x0000000105296788 0x104a18000 + 8906632
29  CRACC                           0x0000000104d36a94 0x104a18000 + 3271316
30  CRACC                           0x0000000104d37d20 0x104a18000 + 3276064
31  UIKitCore                       0x000000022c4e40dc -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 416
32  UIKitCore                       0x000000022c4e5888 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 3380
33  UIKitCore                       0x000000022c4eb580 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1568
34  UIKitCore                       0x000000022cd4ae80 __111-[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:]_block_invoke + 808
35  UIKitCore                       0x000000022cd471e4 +[_UICanvas _enqueuePostSettingUpdateTransactionBlock:] + 168
36  UIKitCore                       0x000000022cd4aae0 -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:] + 252
37  UIKitCore                       0x000000022cd4b4c4 -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability activateEventsOnly:withContext:completion:] + 1080
38  UIKitCore                       0x000000022cd08bcc __82-[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 776
39  UIKitCore                       0x000000022cd08874 -[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 460
40  UIKitCore                       0x000000022cd4d9f0 __125-[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:]_block_invoke + 224
41  UIKitCore                       0x000000022cd4e53c _performActionsWithDelayForTransitionContext + 120
42  UIKitCore                       0x000000022cd4d8a4 -[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:] + 260
43  UIKitCore                       0x000000022cd4682c -[_UICanvas scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 372
44  UIKitCore                       0x000000022c4e99b0 -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 556
45  UIKitCore                       0x000000022c51cdb0 -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 376
46  FrontBoardServices              0x0000000201c39720 -[FBSSceneImpl _didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 456
47  FrontBoardServices              0x0000000201c45070 __56-[FBSWorkspace client:handleCreateScene:withCompletion:]_block_invoke_2 + 284
48  FrontBoardServices              0x0000000201c44690 __40-[FBSWorkspace _performDelegateCallOut:]_block_invoke + 72
49  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001febbc30c _dispatch_client_callout + 20
50  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001febbf8d0 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 240
51  FrontBoardServices              0x0000000201c7b764 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 48
52  FrontBoardServices              0x0000000201c7b3d0 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 448
53  FrontBoardServices              0x0000000201c7ba3c -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 60
54  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001ff144a50 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 28
55  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001ff1449cc __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 92
56  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001ff144284 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 180
57  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001ff13ef64 __CFRunLoopRun + 1032
58  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001ff13e844 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 452
59  GraphicsServices                0x00000002013edbe8 GSEventRunModal + 104
60  UIKitCore                       0x000000022c4ed428 UIApplicationMain + 216
61  CRACC                           0x0000000104d41d14 0x104a18000 + 3317012
62  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001febf4020 start + 4

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001fedc1de8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001fed4567c stat + 8
1   libsqlite3.dylib                0x00000001ff5dc3e4 0x1ff5b5000 + 160740
2   libsqlite3.dylib                0x00000001ff5db454 0x1ff5b5000 + 156756
3   libsqlite3.dylib                0x00000001ff5da114 0x1ff5b5000 + 151828
4   libsqlite3.dylib                0x00000001ff5f95fc 0x1ff5b5000 + 280060
5   libsqlite3.dylib                0x00000001ff5f650c sqlite3_step + 436
6   CRACC                           0x000000010512b734 0x104a18000 + 7419700
7   CRACC                           0x000000010512abec 0x104a18000 + 7416812
8   CRACC                           0x0000000105129e90 0x104a18000 + 7413392
9   CRACC                           0x000000010512a79c 0x104a18000 + 7415708
10  CRACC                           0x0000000105142580 0x104a18000 + 7513472
11  CRACC                           0x0000000105140ab8 0x104a18000 + 7506616
12  CRACC                           0x000000010513625c 0x104a18000 + 7463516
13  CRACC                           0x0000000105146bc4 0x104a18000 + 7531460
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001febbc30c _dispatch_client_callout + 20
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001febbe174 _dispatch_once_callout + 32
16  CRACC                           0x00000001051469c8 0x104a18000 + 7530952
17  CRACC                           0x000000010514675c 0x104a18000 + 7530332
18  CRACC                           0x000000010515e084 0x104a18000 + 7626884
19  ...g_rt.asan_ios_dynamic.dylib  0x000000010863bc18 0x1085f0000 + 310296
20  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001febbad74 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
21  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001febbc30c _dispatch_client_callout + 20
22  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001febc36fc _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 552
23  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001febc4244 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 368
24  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001febcc524 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 588
25  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001fedbbb38 _pthread_wqthread + 316
26  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001fedc1dec start_wqthread + 4

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001fed37b70 swtch_pri + 8
1   ...g_rt.asan_ios_dynamic.dylib  0x0000000108652c78 0x1085f0000 + 404600
2   ...g_rt.asan_ios_dynamic.dylib  0x0000000108635bb0 0x1085f0000 + 285616
3   CRACC                           0x00000001050d4d68 0x104a18000 + 7064936
4   ...g_rt.asan_ios_dynamic.dylib  0x000000010863bdf4 0x1085f0000 + 310772
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001febbad74 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001febbc30c _dispatch_client_callout + 20
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001febbf04c _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 940
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001febcb0f0 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 348
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001febcb95c _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 120
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001fedbbbd8 _pthread_wqthread + 476
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001fedc1dec start_wqthread + 4

Thread 4 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001fed37a68 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001ff14441c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 240
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001ff13f0b8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1372
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001ff13e844 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 452
4   Foundation                      0x00000001ffb405f0 -[NSRunLoop+ 34288 (NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304
5   Foundation                      0x00000001ffb40494 -[NSRunLoop+ 33940 (NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 152
6   UIKitCore                       0x000000022c445cb8 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 140
7   Foundation                      0x00000001ffb3f1d0 -[NSThread main] + 72
8   Foundation                      0x00000001ffc7bdbc __NSThread__start__ + 1044
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001fedb9a04 _pthread_body + 132
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001fedb9960 _pthread_start + 52
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001fedc1df4 thread_start + 4

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001fedc1de8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 6:
0   ...g_rt.asan_ios_dynamic.dylib  0x0000000108652524 0x1085f0000 + 402724
1   ...g_rt.asan_ios_dynamic.dylib  0x000000010864022c 0x1085f0000 + 328236
2   ...g_rt.asan_ios_dynamic.dylib  0x00000001086099ac 0x1085f0000 + 104876
3   libxpc.dylib                    0x00000001fee024e4 _xpc_serializer_append + 204
4   libxpc.dylib                    0x00000001fedf7d74 _xpc_data_serialize_inline_apply + 64
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001febe91bc _dispatch_data_apply_client_callout + 16
6   libxpc.dylib                    0x00000001fedf7630 _xpc_data_serialize + 264
7   libxpc.dylib                    0x00000001fedfbc10 _xpc_dictionary_serialize_apply + 236
8   libxpc.dylib                    0x00000001fedf9994 _xpc_dictionary_apply_node_f + 164
9   libxpc.dylib                    0x00000001fedf9238 _xpc_dictionary_serialize + 176
10  libxpc.dylib                    0x00000001fee029d8 _xpc_serializer_pack + 616
11  libxpc.dylib                    0x00000001fee0874c _xpc_pipe_pack_message + 136
12  libxpc.dylib                    0x00000001fee085fc _xpc_pipe_simpleroutine + 84
13  libxpc.dylib                    0x00000001fedebb50 xpc_pipe_simpleroutine + 64
14  libsystem_trace.dylib           0x00000001fedd17cc ___os_activity_stream_reflect_block_invoke + 40
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001febbc30c _dispatch_client_callout + 20
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001febbf8d0 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 240
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001febbf7ac dispatch_block_perform + 116
18  libsystem_trace.dylib           0x00000001fedd1270 _os_activity_stream_reflect + 540
19  libsystem_trace.dylib           0x00000001fedde258 _os_log_impl_stream + 452
20  libsystem_trace.dylib           0x00000001feddde30 _os_log_impl_flatten_and_send + 6204
21  libnetwork.dylib                0x000000020034453c sa_dst_compare_internal + 412
22  libnetwork.dylib                0x000000020021fce0 nw_resolver_endpoint_should_be_before + 732
23  libnetwork.dylib                0x000000020021f884 __nw_resolver_insert_endpoint_block_invoke + 112
24  libnetwork.dylib                0x00000002003b16f8 __nw_array_apply_block_invoke + 56
25  libxpc.dylib                    0x00000001fedf04c0 xpc_array_apply + 88
26  libnetwork.dylib                0x000000020021f394 nw_resolver_insert_endpoint + 408
27  libnetwork.dylib                0x00000002002210f8 nw_resolver_host_resolve_callback + 3080
28  libsystem_dnssd.dylib           0x00000001fecdb6a8 handle_addrinfo_response + 416
29  libsystem_dnssd.dylib           0x00000001fecdc0ec ConnectionResponse + 196
30  libsystem_dnssd.dylib           0x00000001fecd98a4 DNSServiceProcessResult + 584
31  ...g_rt.asan_ios_dynamic.dylib  0x000000010863c380 0x1085f0000 + 312192
32  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001febbc30c _dispatch_client_callout + 20
33  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001febbf2dc _dispatch_continuation_pop + 408
34  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001febcf42c _dispatch_source_invoke2 + 1204
35  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001febcecac _dispatch_source_invoke + 436
36  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001febc5444 _dispatch_workloop_invoke2 + 632
37  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001febc4f30 _dispatch_workloop_invoke + 432
38  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001febcc524 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 588
39  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001fedbbb38 _pthread_wqthread + 316
40  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001fedc1dec start_wqthread + 4

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001fed45928 write + 8
1   CRACC                           0x00000001050e9960 0x104a18000 + 7149920
2   CRACC                           0x00000001050e9844 0x104a18000 + 7149636
3   CRACC                           0x00000001050e9b50 0x104a18000 + 7150416
4   CRACC                           0x00000001050e9f70 0x104a18000 + 7151472
5   CRACC                           0x00000001050ea034 0x104a18000 + 7151668
6   CRACC                           0x00000001050d0fe4 0x104a18000 + 7049188
7   CRACC                           0x00000001050d1494 0x104a18000 + 7050388
8   ...g_rt.asan_ios_dynamic.dylib  0x000000010863bc18 0x1085f0000 + 310296
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001febbad74 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001febbc30c _dispatch_client_callout + 20
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001febc36fc _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 552
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001febc4244 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 368
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001febcc524 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 588
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001fedbbb38 _pthread_wqthread + 316
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001fedc1dec start_wqthread + 4

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001fedc1de8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 9 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001fed430e4 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001fec9b074 __abort + 156
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001fec9afd8 __abort + 0
3   ...g_rt.asan_ios_dynamic.dylib  0x000000010865d1d4 0x1085f0000 + 446932
4   ...g_rt.asan_ios_dynamic.dylib  0x000000010865b9cc 0x1085f0000 + 440780
5   ...g_rt.asan_ios_dynamic.dylib  0x0000000108645790 0x1085f0000 + 350096
6   ...g_rt.asan_ios_dynamic.dylib  0x000000010865ba54 0x1085f0000 + 440916
7   ...g_rt.asan_ios_dynamic.dylib  0x0000000108648370 0x1085f0000 + 361328
8   ...g_rt.asan_ios_dynamic.dylib  0x0000000108647f24 0x1085f0000 + 360228
9   ...g_rt.asan_ios_dynamic.dylib  0x0000000108648394 0x1085f0000 + 361364
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001fedb9a04 _pthread_body + 132
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001fedb9960 _pthread_start + 52
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001fedc1df4 thread_start + 4

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001fedc1de8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 9 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000001
    x4: 0x0000000000000000   x5: 0x0000000000989680   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000000000000000
    x8: 0x0000000000000800   x9: 0x0000000000009503  x10: 0x000000002240069b  x11: 0x000000023b29fb72
   x12: 0x000000023b29fb72  x13: 0x0000000000000009  x14: 0x0000000000000001  x15: 0x0000000000000881
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x000000022f9b2888  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x000000016b848000  x21: 0x0000000000000000  x22: 0x0000000000009503  x23: 0x000000016b8480e0
   x24: 0x0000000000000000  x25: 0x0000000000000000  x26: 0x0000000000000000  x27: 0x0000000000000000
   x28: 0x0000000000000000   fp: 0x00000001120034c0   lr: 0x00000001fedbab68
    sp: 0x0000000112003490   pc: 0x00000001fed430e4 cpsr: 0x00000000
```

![Here is where i call the function in app delegate:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23Cgp.png)

Comment: Show you code, when you call configure function

Comment: FirebaseApp.configure() Just thatt

Comment: Did you update your pod file?

Comment: Yes before it was in version 5.4.0 firebase and crashes, i updated to 5.9.0 and keep crashing

Comment: @KhôiVNguyễn where you call it ? AppDelegate ? ViewDidLoad? without code is impossible to know where and how the exception is thrown.

Comment: App delegate in the first function and return true

Comment: I upload a screenshot where i call that function, thanks Andrew

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on *FirebaseApp.configure()* and then run the app, does the crash occur before that line executes or after you step through that line?

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling the Address Sanitizer in your scheme

[image]